# Growth rate vs. Absolute correlations

Tags: time-series, correlation, intuition, growth-model

Conceptually, what is the reason why the correlation between growth rates of A and B would be different from correlation between actual A and B? Under what circumstances would the growth rate correlation be higher? How about lower? How about equal?

Comment: Please provide us a context to understand this question!  What are "A" and "B" and how are these quantities related to "growth rates"?

Comment: Ah. It was meant to be a general conceptual question, but I can give an example. Let A = {1, 3, 4, 2} and B = {50, 60, 65, 55}. Then, let A_g = {200%, 33%, -50%} and let B_g = {20%, 8%, -15%}, where A_g and B_g are the sequential growth rates for A and B. So, correlation of A and B is 1, but correlation of A_g and B_g is less than 1. I could make another example where the opposite is true. It seems that it should be a simple thing to understand, but for some reason I'm not getting it conceptually. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @overflowname: Tou should really put the extra info as an edit to your Q

Answer (score 3):

The growth rate of a series of values is approximately equal to the rate-of-change of the logarithm of the series.  (In fact, you can define it that way if you want to measure growth as a continuous measure.)  We know that functions can travel roughly together even if their rates-of-change are very different and *vice versa*, so it is then unsurprising that two series could have a very different correlation to their respective growth rates.

To illustration this phenomenont, consider the following simple example generated in `R`.  As you can see, these two series follow each other reasonable closely, and they are *strongly positively correlated*.  However, their growth rates go in the opposite direction, and are *strongly negatively correlated*.  In series `A` the growth rate starts low and gets higher, but in series `B` the growth rate starts high and gets lower.  Since both growth rates are consistently positive and vary within a relatively small range, both of the underlying series exhibit roughly exponential growth.  This means that the series follow each other reasonably well over the time period (which is quite short) but the growth rates go roughly the opposite way over that same time period.

This example has been constructed specifically to exhibit this type of extreme difference in the correlations.  However, you should note that **this is not as extreme as it can get** --- in fact, it is quite simple to generate other examples with correlations coming arbitrarily close to one and negative one respectively.

[image]

```
#Set values
A <- c(100.012275819031, 101.087470923785, 102.304233382710, 103.617090747768, 
       105.100789689366, 106.684227840111, 108.373669278348, 110.226586551065, 
       112.226941711386, 114.372177239941, 116.652635197791, 119.137611188373, 
       121.767927632902, 124.553460532848, 127.487573878639, 130.703446168312)
B <- c( 99.994766201281, 102.499101327820, 104.958747862204, 107.392611836407, 
       109.772887914615, 112.091157413455, 114.353582409168, 116.544188492527, 
       118.643721908487, 120.613460363055, 122.558227594519, 124.395225200670, 
       126.132882310051, 127.735507732613, 129.256118477392, 130.688740081408)

#Compute growth rates
GA <- rep(0, 15)
GB <- rep(0, 15)
for (i in 1:15) {
  GA[i] <- A[i+1]/A[i] - 1
  GB[i] <- B[i+1]/B[i] - 1 }

#Plot A vs B and growth-rate-A vs growth-rate-B with correlations shown
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(A, B, pch = 19, col = 'red', xlim = c(95, 135), ylim = c(95, 135),
     main = paste0('Correlation = ', round(cor(A,B),6)))
plot(GA, GB, pch = 19, col = 'blue', xlim = c(0.01, 0.026), ylim = c(0.01, 0.026),
     main = paste0('Correlation = ', round(cor(GA,GB),6)),
     xlab = 'Growth Rate for A', ylab = 'Growth Rate for B')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is easy to see if you look at deterministic sequences. The growth rate is given by
$$ 100 \cdot \frac{a_{t+1}-a_t}{a_t} $$
and so if you change the sequence by adding a constant to all terms, the numerator is unchanged but not the denominator. So by adding different constants we can change the growth rates, thus the correlation between growth rates, without changing correlation between the series itself.

An example, computed in R:

```r
 cor(1:5,  101:105)
[1] 1
 cor(gr(1:5),  gr(101:105))
[1] 0.9318379
 cor(gr(1:5),  gr(1001:1005))
[1] 0.9290624
```

where the growth rate is calculated by

```r
 gr <-  
function(x) { 
    n <- length(x)
    (diff(x) / x[1:(n-1)])* 100  
}
```

(and, in R, `1:5` means the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

In all cases here, the absolute sequences has correlation 1, while the correlation of growth rates depends on the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

A general definition of growth rate would include the case in which shrinking is occurring. As it turns out, one can generalize the definition of half-life to include negative values, which correspond to growth rather than halving. From the geometry of the tangent to the logarithm of any function, as below for drug concentration and in general for any $f(t)$
[image]
one can define half-life as a generalization of halving-time for any function at any instant of time using the limits definition of what a derivative is as $$t_{1/2};f(t)=-\ln(2)\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{d\ln[f(t)]}{dt}}=-\ln(2)\dfrac{f(t)}{f'(t)}\;,$$
which is Eq. (6) of [Comparison of the gamma-Pareto convolution with...](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10928-019-09666-z). Finally, note that if one wishes to define the double-life as positive, then one can change the sign above to be positive
$$t_{2};f(t)=\ln(2)\dfrac{f(t)}{f'(t)}\;,$$
in which case half-lives are then negative values. However, no matter how one defines it, via growth, or shrinking, the only way to do either properly is to allow for when the opposite occurs, that is, if one defines doubling-rate as positive, then halving-rate becomes negative.

Finally, there is no reason for an arbitrary vector $\vec{t}$, and arbitrary functions $f$ and $g$ to expect that

$$r\left[\dfrac{f(\vec{t})}{f'(\vec{t})},\dfrac{g(\vec{t})}{g'(\vec{t})}\right]=r[f(\vec{t}),g(\vec{t})]$$

and I don't think that there is any simple answer to the question as posed without specifying what vectors are being considered.